# My SQL Prepared Statement not working

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert some data into a local MYSQL database that I recently installed. This is my first time trying to use MYSQL as I usually use MSSQL. I've never had an issue with prepared statements with MSSQL.

The prepared statement below just will not work, the output of the MySqlCommand comm, always comes out exactly as the initial command string. I've tried replacing all the @ with ? and that doesn't work. I've removed the @ symbol in front of the string and several other combinations. I've googled the issue for several hours with no real answer. Usually someone has some sort of typo in their string. My insert string was directly copied from an insert statement from HeidiSQL and I replaced all the @variables for the C# code and regular insert statements work.

```
 string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;database=busdata;";

         MySqlConnection conn = null;
         conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
         conn.Open();

         try
         {

             MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
             comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO `busdata`.`buses` (`RecordedAtTime`, `DirectionRef`, `JourneyPatternRef`, `PublishedLineName`, `OperatorRef`, `OriginRef`, `DestinationRef`, `DestinationName`, `Monitored`, `Bearing`, `ProgressRate`, `BlockRef`, `VehicleRef`, `OriginAimedDepartureTime`, `ProgressStatus`, `Longitude`, `Latitude`) VALUES (@RecordedAtTime, @DirectionRef, @JourneyPatternRef, @PublishedLineName, @OperatorRef, @OriginRef, @DestinationRef, @DestinationName, @Monitored, @Bearing, @ProgressRate, @BlockRef, @VehicleRef, @OriginAimedDepartureTime, @ProgressStatus, @Longitude, @Latitude`); ";



             foreach (Vehicleactivity bus in buses)
             {              

                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordedAtTime", bus.RecordedAtTime.ToString());
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DirectionRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.DirectionRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JourneyPatternRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.JourneyPatternRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublishedLineName", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.PublishedLineName);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OperatorRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.OperatorRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.OriginRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DestinationRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.DestinationRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DestinationName", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.DestinationName);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monitored", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.Monitored.ToString());
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bearing", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.Bearing.ToString());
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgressRate", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.ProgressRate);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlockRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.BlockRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehicleRef", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.VehicleRef);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginAimedDepartureTime", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.OriginAimedDepartureTime);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgressStatus", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.ProgressStatus);
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.VehicleLocation.Longitude.ToString());
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney.VehicleLocation.Latitude.ToString());
                 comm.Prepare();
                 Console.WriteLine(comm.CommandText.ToString());
                 comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 comm.Parameters.Clear();


             }

         }
         catch (MySqlException ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
```

Comment: when you say "it doesnt work" be more specific.  Are you getting an error?  No data being inserted?  Wrong data being inserted?

Comment: Well the insert statement is exactly the same as the initial string. so without parameters actually inserted, mysql will throw a fit at all the @values. The actual error is "You have an error in your SQL Syntax"

Comment: remove backtick near `@Latitude` in insert query

Comment: Holy Crap! Great Catch! I guess i take back my statement of "Usually someone has some sort of typo in their string." I am now a contributor of such things... thanks @Nagaraj

Comment: @xphacterzero It sounds to me like you have a misunderstanding about how command and parameters work.  The command string wont _ever_ have the parameters replaced in the string.  The underlying data provider will take care of sending that data to the server in the right format though

Comment: Thanks @iamkrillin, you are correct, i was trying to debug it the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a backtick in your insert query near `@location`.Remove backtick..it should work